# Git pull not working with Shell_exec('git pull ');

Tags: php, git, github, gitlab, git-pull

I am trying to use php to run git commands and it works really fine but i have strange problem **git pull.**

```
$auth       = 'https://' . $txtusername . ':' . $txtpassword . '@' . $gitrepo;
$txtbranch = 'master';

shell_exec ("2>&1 git pull $auth $txtbranch");

From https://gitlab.companyname.com/testperson/git-bootcamp
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

I get the output that everything is up to date but actually there are files that have not been pulled yet. Its amazing the following works but not the above one.(directly added the static line to the code)

```
shell_exec ("2>&1 git pull http://testperson:tes%40t123@gitlab.companyname.com master");

From https://gitlab.companyname.com/testperson/git-bootcamp
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating ee30924..c92f020
Fast-forward
 README.md | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Is there something i am doing wrong ? please can you help me on this one.
**Server:linux
,php:7.0
,gitlab(private)**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some error codes or messages

Comment: @Jerry i do not get any error messages. i get is "Already up-to-date".

Comment: Your conclusion is inconsistent with what I see here.  I speculate that the first time you pulled, there really were no new changes, but that afterwards someone pushed something to `master`.

Comment: You can try to make a change to any of the files and run the command again, Push and see

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for replying.Even i thought it was what you speculated but thats not the case here i pushed the changes myself and tried to pull it in another pc using the above code.

Comment: Your workflow is the problem, and I see nothing wrong with your code, as both pulls appear to have hit the Git server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks will definitely look into the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

$auth becomes a URL without some escaping (dont see it) but the example that works uses a escaped URL.

Comment: But the first call appears to have hit the Git server.

Comment: @NiIrrty i definetly tried $auth = escapeshellarg($auth); still dosen't work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right! I must adjust my logic parser :-)